# Equations for power transmitted by a flat belt drive

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-transmission

I've come across two equations that relate power transmitted with the belt tensions:

$$\begin{align}
P &= 10^{-3}(T_1 - T_2)(k)(v) \\
P &= 10^{-3}(T_1 - T_c)(k)(v)
\end{align}$$

As you can see one equation is based on slack side tension ($T_2$) and the other is based on centrifugal tension ($T_c$).

My question is when should I use any one of those two equations to find power.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it shows all the formulae with explanations : http://mechteacher.com/flat-belt-design

Comment: You need about a 100 year old mechanical engineer text book; Any book will do as this was an important subject.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Forgottenbooks.com

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is a static system or an instant of time when the machine is being operated. Usually this would be as the machine starts at maximum force before centrifugal force begins to take effect.

The second equation is when the machine is dynamically being operated and accounts for centrifugal force also.

That's my opinion.